# how to random access with httpclient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

Is there solution to download file using [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) with random access? I want to download file from a specific point rather than from the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking for is the range http header.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084677/determine-if-server-supports-resume-get-request for an example that determines if a server  supports it.

Comment: it's seem working with most of the links, but not with amazon s3 links. sample: http://podcasts.sbnation.com.s3.amazonaws.com/Vergecast_098.mp3

Comment: Not all servers support it, hence them testing to see if a server supported.